# Error on writer.close() of GetRequestStream of FtpWebRequest in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter, ftpwebrequest

So I have a simple ftp transfer function that works on a buffer to send chunks of files to my server. I tried uploading a 300MB file and there was absolutely no issue but AFTER the function had finished sending every single byte of a 1.5GB file, the function crashes on the writer.close().

I then received the following error:
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

```
Public Function upload(ByRef fullpath As String, ByRef filename As String) As Boolean
    If filename <> "" Then
        Try
            Dim clsRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://myserver" & filename), FtpWebRequest)
            clsRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(user, password)
            clsRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            clsRequest.KeepAlive = True
            clsRequest.Timeout = -1
            clsRequest.UsePassive = True


            Dim FileInfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(fullpath)
            Dim bfile() As Byte = New Byte((FileInfo.Length) - 1) {}
            clsRequest.ContentLength = FileInfo.Length


            Dim bytesRead As Integer
            Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
            Using reader As FileStream = FileInfo.OpenRead
                Using writer As Stream = clsRequest.GetRequestStream
                    Do
                        bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                        If bytesRead > 0 Then
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        End If
                    Loop While bytesRead > 0
                    writer.Flush()
                    ''crashes here >>>>>>>
                    writer.Close()
                End Using
                reader.Flush()
                reader.Close()

            End Using

            Return True


        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End If


End Function
```

**EDIT:**

So I found a "solution" and it consists of doing an .abort() on the connection after all the bytes have been transferred. It works perfectly and I don't see any downsides but then I find it kind of sloppy to do so. Would there be any real solution?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/915599):

> This problem occurs when the server or another network device unexpectedly closes an existing Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) connection. This problem may occur when a time-out value on the server or on the network device is set too low. ... The problem can also occur if the server resets the connection unexpectedly, such as if an unhandled exception crashes the server process. Analyze the server logs to see if this may be the issue.

There are multiple solutions presented.

Also, the `Using` block is handling the closing/disposal of `writer` (and another one for `reader`), so you don't need to dispose of it manually, which is what `.Close` is doing.

From [Stream.Close Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method calls Dispose, specifying true to release all resources. You do not have to specifically call the Close method. Instead, ensure that every Stream object is properly disposed. You can declare Stream objects within a using block (or Using block in Visual Basic) to ensure that the stream and all of its resources are disposed, or you can explicitly call the Dispose method.

Comment: Good point on the Using disposing but it now crash on it instead. :S and unfortunately I don't have control over the server as it is a shared hosting.